# I have a table containing in_time and out_time in the format 'HH12:MI'(varchar2).I want to calculate the total time in hours between this column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

[image]

```
select 24 * ROUND(
              to_date(OUT_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') 
              - to_date(IN_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'),
              2
            ) diff_hours 
from   attendances
where  employee_id = 1001;
```

```sql
select 24 * ROUND(
              to_date('2009-07-07 23:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')
              - to_date('2009-07-07 19:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'),
              2
            ) diff_hours
from   dual;
```

Comment: But my query is like  >>>>>>>                                                                                           
              select 24 * ROUND(to_date(OUT_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') 
             - to_date(IN_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'),2) diff_hours                                                          
            From attendances                                                                                                                                          And i can'nt solve it, Please someone solve this issue

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] including: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table (so that we have the data types for your columns); the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the issues and/or errors messages for your query; and the expected output for the sample data.

Answer (score 2):

If you stored (date)time values as strings (which is a bad idea), you'll have to use that format with `to_date`. Using sample data you posted:

```
SQL> with test (employee, in_time, out_time) as
  2    (select 'Palash', '08:45 PM', '08:45 PM' from dual union all
  3     select 'Palash', '07:40 PM', '07:45 PM' from dual union all
  4     select 'Sagor' , '08:10 PM', '08:43 PM' from dual
  5    )
  6  select employee, in_time, out_time,
  7    round((to_date(out_time, 'hh:mi pm') - to_date(in_time, 'hh:mi pm')) * 24, 2) diff
  8  from test;

EMPLOY IN_TIME  OUT_TIME       DIFF
------ -------- -------- ----------
Palash 08:45 PM 08:45 PM          0
Palash 07:40 PM 07:45 PM        .08
Sagor  08:10 PM 08:43 PM        .55

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.And sorry for that i can'nt give you proper information....